# How to access "shared folder" securely in Delphi 10.1 Berlin?

Tags: security, delphi, restriction, delphi-10.1-berlin, shared-directory

Our application is using `Shared Folder` for Import or Export data operations. Many workstations access these shared locations from application.

We need to secure the Shared Folder and a process to access this Shared Folder from applications.

We tried to write a sample application which tries to connect to Shared Folder using `Network Service` Account but we failed to do so. Same is working with `Standard Domain User`.

Code Snippet:

```
Result := LogonUser(PChar(User), PChar(Domain),
    PChar(Password), LogonType, LogonProvider, TokenHandle);

  if Result then
  begin
    Result := ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(TokenHandle);
  end;
```

Anyone has any other suggestion about Securing this workflow?

UPDATE:
I have tried below possibility to use `Network Service` Account but this also fails.

```
>runas /user:"NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
Enter the password for NT AUTHORITY\Network Service:
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to acquire user password
```

Comment: Does the shared folder grant access to the "computer" your application is running on?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - Earlier it was accessible to everyone. but now we are restricting the access. I am trying to execute above sample application on my own machine. I have given access to "Network Service" as well but unable to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the windows api function [WNetAddConnection2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413(v=vs.85).aspx) to add the share.
See sample code at bottom of the linked page.
After the add, you can access to that shared folder.

Don't forget to remove the connection after access with [WNetCancelConnection2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385427(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I have gone through it earlier and it is working fine. But I am looking for another approach which will not required storing of username and password at some location or in database. Other approaches to access the shared folder....

Comment: Create a service which runs in the correct account. Connect your client to that service. But problem will remain at an other level. Clients also should authenticate.